# Collapsing ExpandableListView GroupItem on button click within ChildItem

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Is it possible to collapse the `GroupItem` of an `ExpandableListView` or `ExpandableListAdapter` with a button click within its `ChildItem`?

**What I am trying to achieve is:**

I have an `ExpandableListView` which is being fed by an `ExpandableListAdapter` (extending `BaseExpandableListAdapter`)

Inside the `getChildView()` method of the `ExpandableListAdapter`, I am calling a button (inserted in the child item layout xml) using which I want to close that particular `GroupItem` once user is done reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Set an onClickListener on the button that calls listView.collapseGroup(groupNumber)

Comment: Thanks Gabe. This is what I am trying to achieve but I am not able to get the ExpandableListView instance within the getChildView() method of my ExpandableListAdapter. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Pass it in to the adapter in the constructor, save it in a member variable, and then you can use it wherever